# Get related_name between two models

Tags: django, django-models

How can I programmatically get the related_name or related_query_name from a Django model to another model?

For example, in this code how can I get the name that Parent uses to reference Child with?

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Child(Parent):
    parent = models.OneToOneField(to=Parent, parent_link=True)
    description = models.TextField()
```

Comment: did you mean? `Child.objects.all().values('parent__title')`

Comment: Did you solve you problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following for finding out the `related_query_name`:

```
Child.parent.field.related_query_name()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is builtin functionality to do this, but here is helper function that returns `(related_name, related_query_name)`

```
def get_related_names(model, field_name):
    remote_field = getattr(model, field_name).field.remote_field
    return (remote_field.related_name, remote_field.related_query_name)

get_related_names(Child, 'parent')
```